# What is the limiting distribution of this Markov Chain?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

Take a Markov Chain with state space  $\left\{ 0, 1, \dots, 20 \right\}$. Then we have the rule that given $X_n$:

1. Compute $Z = X_n + 1$ or $Z = X_n - 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each (if the value is at 0 or 20, then it stays 0 or 20 with probability half and goes to 1 or 19 with probability half).
2. If $X_n \ne 11$ then $X_{n+1} = Z$. If $X_n = 11$ then $X_{n+1} = 11$.

The questions are:

If $X_1 = 5$ what is the limiting distribution of this MC?

If $X_1 = 5$ or $X_1 = 15$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each, what is the limiting distribution?

I think these are supposed to be different, but I get that it always just converges to the degenerate r.v 11. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A priori, the pointwise limit of the chain could be 0, 11, or 20, no?

Comment: Sorry I had written it in a misleading way. It is fixed now. I meant that if it is 0 it can't go to -1; it goes to 1 with probability 1/2 and stays at 0 with probability 1/2.

Comment: Then indeed the limiting distribution is Dirac at 11, for every initial distribution.

Comment: Whenever you have a candidate for a limiting distribution, you shall be able to check whether it is the correct one since in the finite case the convergence is exponential.